# How do you use the ansatz of rotationally invariant solutions to derive a ODE from a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

For a) I want to find a ODE by substituting $u(\mathbf x)=f(r)$

I did some calculations. Maybe you could take a look at them.

$$\begin{aligned} &\frac{\partial f(\lvert x\rvert)}{\partial x_1}=f'(\lvert x\rvert)\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}} \\ & \frac{\partial^2 f(\lvert x\rvert)}{\partial x_1^2}=f''(\lvert x\rvert)\frac{x_1^2}{\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}}-f'(\lvert x\rvert)\frac{x_1^2}{\lvert x\rvert^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\ & \space \space . \\ & \space \space . \\ & \frac{\partial^n f(\lvert x\rvert)}{\partial x_i^n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(\lvert x\rvert)}{\lvert x\rvert} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-...\end{aligned}$$

$$\implies \Delta u(\mathbf x)+k^2 u(\mathbf x)=0 \longrightarrow \frac{\partial^n f(\lvert x\rvert)}{\partial x_i^n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(\lvert x\rvert)}{\lvert x\rvert} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-...+k^2f(\lvert x \rvert)=0$$

Is this correct? How do I summarize the last term in my second equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the order of the derivatives with the variable of derivation. You have to compute the second derivative with respect to all the variables and add them up. Let $r=|x|$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial x_i}&=\frac{x_i}{r}\,f'(r),\\
\frac{\partial^2 f(r)}{\partial x_i^2}&=\frac{r-x_i\,\tfrac{x_i}{r}}{r^3}\,f´(r)+\frac{x_i^2}{r^2}\,f''(r)=\frac{r^2-x_i^2}{r^3}\,f´(r)+\frac{x_i^2}{r^2}\,f''(r).
\end{align}$$
Summing from $i=1$ to $n$, and keeping in mind that $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=r^2$, we get
$$
\Delta f(r)=f''(r)+\frac{n-1}{r}\,f´(r).
$$

Comment: Well that makes a ton more sense. It also gives me the correct equation for b). Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a quick question. Shouldn't it be $\frac{n-1}{r}$?

Comment: Thank you for noticing. Corrected.